# bash script check if file have permission other than 444 or read-only

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to check in a list of different folders if specific .php file exist and have specific permission, actually I don't want these files to have any sort of write permissions, just read-only, and read-only by any owner, group, others. So that would be 444 permission.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# List all permissions

for dir in /home/user/client*/stream*/mp4; do
    config_file="${dir}/stream.php"
    if [ -f "$config_file" ]; then
        if [ "$config_file" != '0444' ]; then
            echo "Writable file in $dir"
        fi
    else
        echo "The stream.php file does not exist in $dir"
    fi
done
```

Of course I wanted to try to get some help from chatgpt but it only gives me the wrong answers.

I also tried `[ -w "$config_file" ]` which is suggested in some docs but it always returns me: `Writable file in $dir` And I know for sure files are not writtable.
The other suggestions are with `-perm` command but this gives me syntax error in line `if [ "$config_file"`

Edit: -w returns file is writable because as root i can write to files even if the files have read-only permission or 444

Comment: `-w` definitely checks if a file is writable. Can you provide a reproducible demonstration where it returns the wrong result?

Comment: `[ "$config_file" != '0444' ]` obviously checks whether the string in the variable `config_file` is not exactly the four characters `0444`. Also, the permissions are wrong; it is also writable if the permissions are 0755, or 0666, or 0750, or ...

Comment: Just use the `-r` (readable) comparison, e.g. `if [ -r "$config_file" ]; then` is all you need to test if the file is readable. Then use `-w` for (writable). There is also `-s` (file exists and is non-empty). Just see [man 1 bash](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) under the heading `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` for all of the comparisons available.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you got `-w` to give you the wrong answer, but another way to do this is by using `stat --format=%a file_name`, which will print the permission bits in octal (e.g. 444 in the case you're looking for).

To check the value, change the condition to: `if [ $(stat --format=%a "$config_file") != 444 ]; then`

*I suspect that you need a better understanding of what you need to do though. A file isn't just "writable" or not, it has three different categories of users that have different permissions (owner, group, and everyone else). There are also permissions for the parent directory. You must also have an understanding of who you're trying to protect from (which users, processes, what permissions they run with, etc).*

Comment: I suspect that you need a better understanding of what you need to do though. I understand that part well, I want files to be read-only, nothing else, for groups, owner, or anyone else, they can't have execute or write permissions. So correct would be 444 permission, read-only for everyone. It gives me wrong answer with -w probably as sudo i can write any file.

Comment: Yes, `sudo` will give you the "wrong" answer, but it's also the wrong way to ask. You need to ask as the user(s) who you are trying to guard against, not as root. 444 does mean read for everyone, but keep in mind the owner of the file can modify those bits given the right circumstance.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, the owner and group for each folder and file inside that folder is different. `client2/stream1/` is owned by `client2` and `stream1` group, and `client5/stream2` is owned by `client5` and `stream2` group. And `client2` can modify and change permission of file inside `client2/stream1/` via ftp but he can't change file inside `client5/stream2` and write to it if it's read-only.

Comment: Sounds like you could go with the more standard 644 perms then - read/write for the owner, read only for everyone else.

Comment: If this script is intended to fix perms instead of just checking them, you can simply run a one-liner like `chmod -R go-w /home/user/client*` (which removes write permission for group+others from /home/user/clientX and everything under it). You also should set up `umask` so new files are created with the correct perms from the start.